# javascript/json : How to access the multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, json, multidimensional-array

From server side to client side receiving the value in the javascript variable.  How to get the length of the array x and how to access/retrieve the value from x.
.

```
var x=JSON.parse('{"Array1":[{"Task":"Feature 1.1.3"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.4"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.2"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.1"}], 
"Array2":[{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":283.33},{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":133.33},{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":50.00},{"OverallSubtaskDuration":3.00,"OverallSubtaskPercentage":50.00}]
 }');
```

Comment: `x.Array1.length` or `x['Array1'].length`, `x.Array2.length` or `x['Array2'].length`, `x.Array1[0]`, etc.

Comment: `x` is an object and therefor has no "length"

Comment: how to access and retrieve values from Array1 or how to loop Array1

Comment: Using x variable(length), i want to loop Array1 and Array2 by default Any possible

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.keys to get the keys of the object in an array and then can access the values of Array1 and Array2.

```
var x=JSON.parse('{"Array1":[{"Task":"Feature 1.1.3"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.4"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.2"},{"Task":"Feature 1.1.1"}], 
"Array2":[{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":283.33},{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":133.33},{"OverallSubtaskPercentage":50.00},{"OverallSubtaskDuration":3.00,"OverallSubtaskPercentage":50.00}]
 }');
//This will return all the keys of your in an array.
Object.keys(x).forEach(e=>{
      console.log(x[e]);
});
var lengthOfX = Object.keys(x).length;
```